# Vim visual selection method differs between Windows & Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, windows, gvim

In Linux vim and gvim, I can make a visual selection by pressing `V` (e.g., `v` VISUAL or  `Shift`+`V` VISUAL LINE), releasing it, and using movement keys (e.g., arrows) to highlight the desired text.

In Windows gvim, however, I must hold down `Shift` while I make my selection. Also, `Ctrl`+`V` (block) selection is supplanted by the Windows paste, and I can select text without `v` at all, like the common Windows method of `Shift`+arrow keys. I don't want any of this in my vim.

This is a minor annoyance at best, but there's probably a way to make Windows use the former (Linux) behavior of only pressing `V` once. I've scoured the docs to no avail. How can I dispense with all of this Windows stuff and get consistent behavior between my Windows and  Linux environments?

Comment: Which version are you using?  The version I have seems to work fine.

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:59:02)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-46
Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When gvim starts, it sources a file called `mswin.vim` via the `_vimrc` file.   In the `mswin.vim` file the keys are remapped.  You can undo this two ways.  One is edit the `mswin.vim` file and remove the mapping (not recommended).  A second easier potentially less invasive way is to edit the `_vimrc` file.

```
 1. Start gvim as Administrator.  
 2. Click Edit->Startup Settings (This will load the _vimrc file)
 3. The beginning of the file will look something like this.

set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

 4.  Delete the line that sources mswin.vim and sets mswin behavior and change set nocompatible to set compa`enter code here`tible.  The end result will look something like this.

set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
```

This should fix your problem.

If you want it to behave more like vi than vim, you can change `nocompatible` to `compatible`

Comment: Fantastic! My pinky fingers thank you. I'll upvote when I have the rep on this SE site. If it's not too much trouble, would you mind sharing how you figured this out?

Comment: Honestly.  Semi educated-guessing/random clicking of the settings menu options.  When the config file came up, I tried deleting the windows line and it worked.  :)

Comment: Well, that explains it, then. My inelastic old brain just about never thinks to put **click** and **text editor** in the same thought-bubble. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The easy method to resolve this issue is just to add:

```
set keymodel-=stopsel
```

to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\_vimrc` file (for example after the `behave mswin` line).

[Source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_arrow_keys_work_in_visual_mode_under_Windows).